# In AWS Lambda an error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hello everyone I am new to AWS, In my use case I am trying to access objects stored in S3 bucket using AWS Lambda Function (Runtime: Python 3.11)  but when a new object is uploaded in S3 bucket I am getting the following error-
Error processing assignment: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
My python code snippet is -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Extract S3 event details
        bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        object_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

        # Process the assignment PDF file with the given bucket_name and object_key
        subject = 'UnknownSubject'  # Default value
        class_section = 'UnknownClassSection'  # Default value

        # Extract subject and class/section from the object key
        # Assuming the object key format is "Subject_Class_Section_assignment.pdf"
        parts = object_key.split('_')
        if len(parts) == 4 and parts[3] == 'assignment.pdf':
            subject = parts[0]
            class_section = parts[1] + parts[2]

        # Retrieve the teacher's custom message .txt file from the teacher's S3 bucket
        try:
            teacher_bucket_name = 'examplebucket90'  # Replace with the teacher's Custom message S3 bucket name
            teacher_message_key = f'{subject}_Teacher_{class_section}_Message.txt'
            teacher_message_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=teacher_bucket_name, Key=teacher_message_key)
            teacher_message = teacher_message_object['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error retrieving teacher's custom message: {e}")
            teacher_message = 'No custom message provided by teacher'
```

for the above code i am uploading a pdf file of assignment (English_1A_assignment.pdf)in a S3 bucket. Let the name of this bucket is 'triggerbucket67' and this bucket triggers my lambda my new object file is uploaded in the same bucket.

On the other hand there is another S3 bucket 'examplebucket90' in which a custom message related to uploaded object in 'triggerbucket67'bucket is uploaded. In this bucket the format of custom message.txt file is 'English_1A_Message.txt'.
But when lambda triggers the above two errors are showing.
Can someone please tell me is there any issue with the names of the objects saved in the above two buckets or there is some other point which I am not considering in my use case . I have given the appropriate permission to Lambda to access the objects from S3 buckets (In my use case I am using 'AmazonS3FullAccess' permission in the IAM role related to my Lambda Function.

Comment: It's not about permissions. There's simply no S3 object with that key in that bucket at the time you make the get_object call. Print out the value of `teacher_message_key`. Is it what you expected? Does that object actually exist?

Comment: I think your problem is that `English_1A_assignment.pdf` has 3 parts not 4, and their indexes are 0-2, not 0-3. It doesn't match your expected format of `Subject_Class_Section_assignment.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod My issue has been resolved

Comment: @raj Glad to hear it! In the interest of cleaning up Stack Overflow, would you please post the resolution as an answer, and self-accept it?

Comment: Alternately @jarmod could post the solution provided and you could accept that too.

Comment: @Mike Fiedler If we are uploading object in S3 bucket as English_1A_assignment.pdf then in our code snippet we have to use the below                                                                        # Extract Subject, Class, and Section from the object key                                             # Assuming the object key format is "Subject_ClassSection_assignment.pdf"      
        parts = object_key.split('_')
        if len(parts) == 3 and parts[2] == 'assignment.pdf':
            Subject = parts[0]
            ClassSection = parts[1]

Comment: @raj does the answer below resolve the problem? If not, please provide specifics about what problem you still face.

Comment: @jarmod my issue has been resolved, thanks for your valuable suggestion

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `English_1A_assignment.pdf` has 3 underscore-separated parts not 4. It doesn't match your expected format of `Subject_Class_Section_assignment.pdf`.

Consequently, your code makes a GetObject request for an object key that does not exist and this results in `NoSuchKey`.

You can convert "English_1A_assignment.pdf" into "English_1A_message.txt" as follows:

```
def pdf2txt(s):
    if s.endswith("_assignment.pdf"):
        return s[0:-14] + "message.txt"
    return None

print(pdf2txt("English_1A_assignment.pdf"))
```